# cURL login loses session variables when redirected

Tags: php, session, redirect, curl, session-cookies

I have 2 sites that are the same, but different databases and data.  One site is www.somesite.com and the other is sub.somesite.com.  What I am doing is if someone logs into www.somesite.com and the login details don't match www.somesite.com, but they do match sub.somesite.com, then use cURL to submit the information and log them in.  I have the cURL working great:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$p) {
  if ($post != "") {
    $post .= "&";
  }
  $post .= $key."=".$p;
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sub.somesite.com"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$cArray = curl_getinfo($ch);
$newURL = $cArray[url];
echo str_replace('</head>','<base href="'.$newURL.'" /></head>',$result);
curl_close($ch);
```

What this does is collects the post variables, submits them to the other site and adds a base url so that the paths are correct.

The problem that I am having is any other page after.  So say I am on somesite.com, submit the data.  Even though it is going to sub.somesite.com/welcome.php, it displays in the address bar somesite.com and the information is stored in the cookies.txt.  Now when I click a link (sub.somesite.com/page2.php) on sub.somesite.com/welcome.php, it redirects to the login page because the sessions are in the cookies.txt and now aren't accessible.

How would I make the sessions continue to work on all pages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because CURL executes it on the server not on the client (browser). Your server might have the users cookies but the user does not.

You want to set the cookies for the browser using [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and forget about the Curl.

Comment: Makes sense, but they use $_SESSION instead of $_COOKIE. I assume I will have to change both URLs then? The first to set the cookie and the second to look for the cookie and convert to session?

Comment: Well, maybe passing the session cookie (usually named PHPSESSID) to the client, and then redirecting, would make it work.

Comment: But forget about the curl. You can just make it set the session cookie for that domain using session_set_cookie_params - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: So I would put this just before the session_start() on both and make sure it is .somesite.com as the domain?

Comment: Using session_set_cookie_params before each session_start() and setting the sessions on the first domain works.  Not exactly what I was after, but I am able to work with it to get the desired result. Thanks.